# How do you validate photos in a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a product model in rails that has_many: photos. I want to add validations that make sure you cannot create a product without adding a photo. I have tried adding  validates_attachment_presence :image on the photo model but the product model is still getting saved without photos. How can I validate the images? Also I want the users to add at least 5 photos

```
//product model
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base     
   has_many   :photos
end

//photo model
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    validates_attachment_presence :image
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't post your table schema, I tried to guess it.

Then, to validate the `presence/format` of photos you can use the [validation-helpers](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers) and to check the minimum number of photos you can create a custom validator this way:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
    before_save :images_limit_min

    private    
    def images_limit_min
        return if self.photos.empty?
        errors[:base] << "You must to upload at least 5 images" if self.photos.length < 5
    end
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    validates :product_id, presence: true, format: { with: %r{ \.(png|jpg|jpeg)$ }i, message: "custom message" }
end
```

**Note:** The structure may not be fully correct, but I hope you got the way that you should go.

Comment: This won't work; if Product has_many Photos, then it's Photos which have a product_id, not the other way around. Edit: Although, the images_limit_min is on the right track; it's just the validates :photo_id part that doesn't work

Comment: @philomory good point man.. it's because it's hard to abstract everything without any project in your front :D I think if I move the validates to `photos` it should work.

Comment: That will work, and is probably a good idea to do, but doesn't directly address the OP's question; it makes sure you can't have a Photo that isn't associated with any Product, which is often (though not always) something you want to ensure, but not actually mentioned by the question.